# Preferred way to include license for redistributed open-source libraries

Tags: open-source, licensing

If my app uses library A - GNU license, library B - BSD license and library C - MIT license, and I want to pack these libraries together with my app in one zip file, what is the preferred way to mention the licenses? Do I write a license.txt that is a list of the three libraries and their respective license texts?

Comment: If your application uses a GPL-ed library (like `readline` library) it is itself GPL-ed, then you need to include the GPLv3 text, usually as `COPYING3`. If the library is LGPL-ed (like Gtk is) things are different. I would pack each library's source archive (e.g. `zip` or `tar`) in your Zip file, and you could just add an URL link to them.

Comment: Basile, it would be the best if everything the user needed is in one package but your suggestion is simple and safe. Thanks.

Comment: You could also make `*.deb` packages for common Linux distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the preferred way to mention the licenses? Do I write a license.txt that is a list of the three libraries and their respective license texts?

It's common you create a file called COPYING containing the packages licensing first and then you list those parts you use (this software contains components under their own license). Exemplary I find the [Licenses compiled by The XFree86 Project](http://www.xfree86.org/current/LICENSE.html), could give some inspiration. Additionally there is [Maintaining Permissive-Licensed Files in a GPL-Licensed Project: Guidelines for Developers](http://www.softwarefreedom.org/resources/2007/gpl-non-gpl-collaboration.html).